# Why are all SVD's obtained by multiplying columns of $U$ and $V$ by $-1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix can have several different single value decompositions (SVDs). Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with $n$ different singular values $\sigma_1 > \sigma_2> \dots > \sigma_n$.

Why can all SVDs $A=U\Sigma V^T$ be obtained from each other by multiplying some columns of $U$ by $-1$ and simultaneously multiplying the same columns of $V$ by $-1$?

Comment: Anyone can help ?

Comment: length of the columns don't change when you multiply by $\pm 1.$

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful to note that if $u_1,\dots,u_n$ are the columns of $U$ and $v_1,\dots,v_n$ the columns of $V$, then we can write
$$
U\Sigma V^T = \sigma_1 u_1v_1^T + \sigma_2 u_2 v_2^T + \cdots + \sigma_n u_n v_n^T
$$
verify that multiplying $u_i$ and $v_i$ by $-1$ (for any $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$) does not affect the sum.  Verify also that multiplying a column of a unitary (orthogonal) matrix by $-1$ still gives you an orthogonal matrix.